# Online flowchart web-app

Tags: gratis, web-apps, charts

I am looking for a free flow-charting web-app.

This is basically for creating flowcharts for a program's structure, and so, I would like (as many as possible):

- font, block and line colour options
- looping (ie. joining an arrow from one block back to another)
- free positioning (doesn't have to be in one vertical line)
- pictures (that I upload)

I *need* it to be free, online, exportable to any format (PDF is preferable), and cloud storage with the app is even better!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using **[Draw.IO](https://www.draw.io/)** for this kind of job:

[image: drawio storage] [image: drawio templates] [image: drawio programming]
<sup>*DrawIO* screenshots (source: [Draw.IO](https://www.draw.io/); click images for larger variants)</sup>

- **font, block and line colour options:** Yes.
- **joining an arrow from one block back to another:** If I understand you (and DrawIO) correctly: yes (admitted, I've not explicitely tried).
- **free positioning:** Definitely yes.
- **pictures (that I upload):** Yes to the first, even includes an image search by license. And after a little check: Yes to the second, you can upload from an URL you specify (where you upload your image to first).
- **cloud storage:** supports GoogleDrive and OneDrive – as well as your local harddrive and browser storage

It's pretty neat, you can export as...

- XML (to load it again at a later time)
- Graphics file (PNG, GIF, JPEG)
- PDF, SVG, HTML

PS: There's even a [drawio app](https://apps.owncloud.com/content/show.php/drawio?content=166206) to integrate with [ownCloud](https://owncloud.org/):

[image: drawio ownCloud app] [image: drawio ownCloud app]
<sup>*drawio* ownCloud app (source: [ownCloud apps](https://apps.owncloud.com/content/show.php/drawio?content=166206); click images for larger variants)</sup>

[See it in action in a Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tz865R8AxKM).

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/E1SFOxx.png works for me :)

Comment: *LOL* I like the green box #D As for the red one: I don't count myself as an "experienced DrawIO user", but I use it every now and then – though mostly for "easy stuff" [like this](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/external-sd/info) :) Oh, and BTW: You can even integrate DrawIO with your ownCloud installation. There's an app for that :)

Comment: That's a lot of effort for a tag wiki that nobody's going to see ;p and that's a pretty pro flowchart according to me (at least by my standards ;). The ownCloud option's even better! Thanks :)

Comment: I'm using that one in my (Android) books as well, so I don't feel the effort wasted :) And glad I could even give double-help (a pity you can't upvote twice now ;) Enjoy!

Comment: Another great thing about Drawio is that you don't need an account or any sign up process!